# Access json objects using variables as keys in postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a json `poll_result`

```
{"total_votes":1,"yes":1,"no":0}
```

and I have a variable that has the key

```
vote_to = _poll_response::json#>>'{vote}';
```

and that returns the `"yes"`.

Now I want to access `poll_result` json based on the vote_to variable's value, so I am trying

```
raise notice '%',poll_result::json#>>'{||vote_to||}';
```

but this is printing `<NULL>`. Even I have tried like

```
raise notice '%,%',poll_result,poll_result::json#>>'{''||vote_to||''}';
```

but the result is same `<NULL>`.

Please help!!!

Comment: At least give the reason why to close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the example on how to use a variable with `->>` and `#>>` operators:

```
do $$
declare
    pool_result json = '{"total_votes":1,"yes":1,"no":0}';
    vote_to text = 'yes';
begin
    raise notice 'yes: %', pool_result ->> vote_to;
    -- or
    raise notice 'yes: %', pool_result #>> array[vote_to]; 
end;
$$

NOTICE:  yes: 1
NOTICE:  yes: 1
```

If the the value of the variable is in double quotes you should trim them:

```
do $$
declare
    pool_result json = '{"total_votes":1,"yes":1,"no":0}';
    vote_to text = '"yes"';
begin
    raise notice 'yes: %', pool_result ->> trim(vote_to, '"');
    -- or
    raise notice 'yes: %', pool_result #>> array[trim(vote_to, '"')]; 
end;
$$
```

Comment: not working.. 
`raise notice '%,%',vote_to,poll_result::json #>> array[vote_to];` is printing
`NOTICE:  "yes",<NULL>`

Comment: yes!! this is working.. the `poll_result` is from database table whose type is json. Then why I need to trim "